# Inside out Spiral Matrix Java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Given a N*N matrix; I want to print it in spiral form, that too inside out.

eg.

given a matrix

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11  12
13 14 15 16
```

I want to print as 7 6 10 11 12 8 4 3 2 1 5 9 13 14 15 16

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

edit -

Here is what I have done -

I have found the starting node based on N is even or odd.
I have found the relationship of traversal in each cycle based on row, column indexes - 
    Left = -1, -3,-5 ...
    Down = +1,+3,+5 ...
    Right = +2,+4,+6 ...
    Up = -2,-4,-6 ...

But now I am struggling to put together this in code.

Comment: Try your ideas on a square matrix first (with odd dimension).

Comment: This kind of traversal is only possible with square matrices. I am able to find one solution. Please check and suggest if I can optimize it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Please let me know any optimized solution. There you go -

```
public class SpiralMatrix {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    int size=sc.nextInt();
    int[][] arr=new int[size][size];
    int r,c;
    int elements =size*size;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
            arr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();

    int count=0;

    int left=-1,down=1,right=2,up=-2;

    if(size%2==0) {r=size/2-1; c=size/2;}       
    else r=c=size/2;
    System.out.print(arr[r][c]+" ");

    try{
    while(count<elements-1){
    for(int i=0;i>left;i--){
        c=c-1;
        System.out.print(arr[r][c]+" ");
        count++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<down;i++){
        r=r+1;
        System.out.print(arr[r][c]+" ");
        count++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<right;i++){
        c=c+1;
        System.out.print(arr[r][c]+" ");
        count++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i>up;i--){
        r=r-1;
        System.out.print(arr[r][c]+" ");
        count++;
    }

    left=left-2;
    down=down+2;
    right=right+2;
    up=up-2;

    }

    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to think of it as a checkerboard, where all the squares are painted in white.
 
You start by painting the square in the middle of the board in black. 
You do the same for the square on the left.
From there, you'll need to know if you continue painting to the left, or if you go down. If the square down your current position is already painted in black, you continue to the left. Otherwise, you go down.
To know if a square is already painted in black or not, you'll need a mask.

Having this in mind, this is what I came up with, using only one loop.

I tried to comment the code enough, so it may seem too long... Anyway, I think it can still be shorten.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SpiralMatrix{

    public static final int UP = 0;
    public static final int LEFT = 1;
    public static final int RIGHT = 2;
    public static final int DOWN = 3;

     public static void main(String []args){        

        // The input matrix
        int[][] matrix= {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

        // The input matrix  dimension
        int matrixLength = matrix.length;

        //The number of elemets of the input matrix
        int numberOfElements = matrixLength * matrixLength;

        // The output is a single dimensional array containing the elements of the input matrix as a spiral
        int[] spiralMatrix = new int[numberOfElements] ;

        // The matrix mask help to decide which is the next direction or the next element to pick from the input matrix
        // All the values of the mask are initialized to zero. 
        int[][] mask = new int[matrixLength][matrixLength];

                //The first element of the output(the spiral) is always the middle element of the input matrix
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int colIndex = 0;

    if(matrixLength%2 == 0){
        rowIndex = matrix.length/2 - 1;
    } else {
        rowIndex = matrix.length/2;
    }
    colIndex = matrix.length/2;

    // Each time an element from the input matrix is added to the output spiral, the corresponding element in the mask is set to 1
    spiralMatrix[0] = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
    mask[rowIndex][colIndex] = 1; 

        // The first direction is always to the left
        int nextDirection = LEFT;

        // This is a counter to loop through all the elements of the input matrix only one time
        int i = 0;

        while(i < numberOfElements - 1){    
            i++;

            // Check which direction to go (left, down, right or up)
            switch(nextDirection){

                case LEFT :
                    // From the input matrix, take the number at the left of the current position(which is the middle of the input matrix) and add it to the spiral
                    colIndex -=1;
                    spiralMatrix[i] = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];

                    //Update the mask
                    mask[rowIndex][colIndex] = 1;

                    // Decide which direction(or element in the input matrix) to take next.
                    // After moving to the left, you only have two choices : keeping the same direction or moving down
                    // To know which direction to take, check the mask
                    if(mask[rowIndex+1][colIndex] == 1){
                        nextDirection = LEFT;
                    }else{
                        nextDirection = DOWN;
                    }
                    break;

                case DOWN : 
                    rowIndex +=1;
                    spiralMatrix[i] = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
                    mask[rowIndex][colIndex] = 1;
                    if(mask[rowIndex][colIndex+1] == 1){
                        nextDirection = DOWN;
                    }else{
                        nextDirection = RIGHT;
                    }
                    break;

                case RIGHT : 
                    colIndex +=1;
                    spiralMatrix[i] = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
                    mask[rowIndex][colIndex] = 1;
                    if(mask[rowIndex-1][colIndex] == 1){
                        nextDirection = RIGHT;
                    }else{
                        nextDirection = UP;
                    }
                    break;

                case UP : 
                    rowIndex -=1;
                    spiralMatrix[i] = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex];
                    mask[rowIndex][colIndex] = 1;
                    if(mask[rowIndex][colIndex-1] == 1){
                        nextDirection = UP;
                    }else{
                        nextDirection = LEFT;
                    }
                    break;  
            }
         }

         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
         System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mask));
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spiralMatrix));
     }

}
```

You can debug it to see how the input matrix, the mask, and the output evolve at each iteration. I only commented the first switch case, but let me know if further explanations are necessary for the others.
Hope it helps.

Comment: It is a good solution that you are using a parallel array to navigate through your input array.I  guess you should also include a scenario for odd size matrix like 3*3 or 5*5.

Comment: The only thing that changes is the way the middle element of the input array is choosen, which is different depending on if the input matrix order is even or uneven. I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the movement of only 1 dimension of the spiral you'll see the pattern.  eg. vertically, you move up 1, then down 2, then up 3, then down 4, etc. Then you just alternate between horizontal and vertical dimensions.

Here is an example:

```
int[][] matrix = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4},
        { 5, 6, 7, 8},
        { 9,10,11,12},
        {13,14,15,16}};
int matrixLength = matrix.length * matrix[0].length;
int y = matrix.length/2 - 1;
int x = matrix[0].length/2 - 1;
System.out.println(matrix[y][x]);

boolean isDirectionDown = true;
boolean isDirectionRight = true;
boolean isMoveHorizontal = true;
int xLength = 1;
int yLength = 1;
int stepCount = 0;
outer: while (true) {
    if (isMoveHorizontal) {
        for (int i = 0; i < xLength; i++) {
            if (stepCount == matrixLength-1) {
                break outer;
            }
            x += (isDirectionRight) ? 1 : -1;
            stepCount++;
            System.out.println(matrix[y][x]);
        }
        xLength++;
        isDirectionRight = !isDirectionRight;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < yLength; i++) {
            if (stepCount == matrixLength-1) {
                break outer;
            }
            y += (isDirectionDown) ? 1 : -1;
            stepCount++;
            System.out.println(matrix[y][x]);
        }
        yLength++;
        isDirectionDown = !isDirectionDown;
    }
    isMoveHorizontal = !isMoveHorizontal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to put the matrix into a two-dimensional array like so:

```
int[][] matrix = {{ 1, 2, 3, 4},
                  { 5, 6, 7, 8},
                  { 9,10,11,12},
                  {13,14,15,16}};
```

Then, use some loops to create a spiralling algorithm. A typical square spiralling algorithm starts at a point then moves in a direction by x, turns 90 degrees and moves in that direction by x, then increments x by two, and repeats until it reaches the outer edge.

Your outer loop may very well look something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<matrix.length; i+=2){
    ...
}
```

Also note that the number of movements your program will make should always be `matrix.length*2-1`: so your loop could also look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<matrix.length*2-1; i++){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that is exactly where I am struggling. I am not able to control the movement in either direction. I have even used 4 variable for Left, right, up, down movements but I could not calculate the exact amount of cycles required for size N to complete the entire traversal.

Comment: @vv88 Well the number of cycles required should always be `(length*2)-1`. I will update my answer to reflect this comment.